# How can I improve the accuracy of my prediction from a decision tree model using sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have created a decision tree model in Python using sklearn, and it takes data from a large public data set that relates human factors (age, bmi, sex, smoking, etc) to cost of medical care that insurance companies pay each year. I split the data set with a test size of .2, but mean absolute error and mean squared error are incredibly high. I tried doing different splits (.5, .8) but I have not gotten any different results. The prediction model appears to be quite off in some areas but I am not sure what part is lacking and what I need to improve. I have attached photos of my output (through an IMGUR link as I cannot add photos) as well as my code, and I appreciate any guidance in the right direction!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrOMv.jpg

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('insurance.csv')

LE = LabelEncoder()
LE.fit(dataset.sex.drop_duplicates())
dataset.sex = LE.transform(dataset.sex)
LE.fit(dataset.smoker.drop_duplicates())
dataset.smoker = LE.transform(dataset.smoker)
LE.fit(dataset.region.drop_duplicates())
dataset.region = LE.transform(dataset.region)

print("Data Head")
print(dataset.head())
print()
print("Data Info")
print(dataset.info())
print()



for i in dataset.columns:
    print('Null Values in {i} :'.format(i = i) , dataset[i].isnull().sum())


X = dataset.drop('charges', axis = 1) 
y = dataset['charges'] 


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2, random_state=0)  

regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)  

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual Value': y_test, 'Predicted Values': y_pred})  
print(df)

print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain things you can do if you are not doing already:

1. Use `StandardScaler()` from scikit-learn on non-categorical columns/features.
2. Use `GridSearchCV` from scikit-learn to search for appropriate hyper-parameters, instead of doing it manually. Although, choosing to do so manually may give you some sense of which parameter values might work.
3. Check the documentation of `DecisionTreeRegressor` carefully to make sure that your implementation is in agreement with the documentation.

See if this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely followed the documentation but I will look into StandardScaler and GridSearchCV.

Comment: @Cassie Please consider **voting up** this answer. Thank you for choosing it as the **accepted** answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xgboost`, which is the using a boosting algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that now!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Aggregating (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) would be an easy way to reduce the variance of your estimator. There is little additional code needed if you are already using an sklearn regressor. Below is an example of how you could use a simply bagged estimator to reduce the variance of your model:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2, random_state=0)  

regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor() 
b_regressor = BaggingRegressor(regressor, n_estimators = 100, max_features=3, max_samples=.5)  # get Boostrap aggregation ensemble regressor 

# Fit+predict using regular regressor
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)  
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test) 

# Fit predict using bootstrap aggregation
b_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)  
y_b_pred = b_regressor.predict(X_test) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual Value': y_test, 'Predicted Values': y_pred, 'Bagging Predicted Values': y_b_pred})  
print(df)

print('Mean Absolute Error (Regular):', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
print('Mean Squared Error (Regular):', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print('Root Mean Squared Error (Regular):', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))

print('Mean Absolute Error (Bagging):', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_b_pred))
print('Mean Squared Error (Bagging):', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_b_pred))
print('Root Mean Squared Error (Bagging):', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_b_pred)))
```

Comment: Hmm, I actually ended up getting a higher MAE with that! I wonder if there's something I'm missing.